# Xamarin Forms Masterdetail back button navigation with Prism

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

So I have built a Xamarin Forms app with Prism and have a Masterdetail page.
Current flow of the app is

```
> MasterDetail
>       - ContentPage1
>       - ContentPage2
>       - ContentPage3
```

All these content names have been added in a formatted Listview in MasterDetail and the click of these listview item is handled is done in the MasterDetailViewModel where based on the item clicked it does a navigation like

```
_navigationservice.NavigateAsync("MasterdetailPage/"+selectedPage);
```

So the navigation happens correctly here.
Now if I select another ContentPage from the MasterDetailPage and try going back, all my stack content are gone and the app is just suspended, where as the behaviour I'm looking for should send me back to the previous selected ContentPage with the Masterdetial page.

I'm not sure what can I do other than handling the backbutton in individual ContentPages but thought it would mess up the code really bad.

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong.

Edit: I've also tried adding a NavigationPage before the ContentPage but that did not help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not related to prism. This is the expected behavior of MasterDetail Navigation. You have a menu and items. Why would you want to go back to selected page? What if a user selected ContentPage1 -> ContentPage2 -> ContentPage1->ContentPage2
do you expected the back button to go back to to page 1 then page 2 then page 1 and so on?

Comment: Usually , what you do in the MasterDetail menu is the following, you catch the event when user pressed the back button and ask the user to confirm closing the app. This only happens in Android devices since they have physical button. Please clarify what you need and update your question to get the required answer

Comment: @Ali123: My scene is more like a normal app where he has HomePage and SettingsPage so if he goes to Settings page and goes back its natural to go back to the homepage and not close the app. But what you're saying is right too I guess I have to override the backbutton and handle the case.

Comment: This is what I do in my apps. But , I am facing a small issue. DisplayAlert is async and will not wait for user response on yes or no OnBackButtonPressed(). I think that is why they don't use it and use some toast messages or other views. I can share the code of OnBackButtonPressed if you want but the handling issue is still there

Comment: But I somehow believe if I call the NavigateAsync from my ContentPage then I can come back to the same page. Let me try that. I probably have to use Messaging center to send the trigger from the MasterDetail page.

Comment: If you checked @brianlagunas introduction of Prism, you will learn that Prism is a smart framework that knows that you are in a tabbed page or masterdetail page. It will do the navigation according to the page it's in